# Changing default settings in SQL Server Enterprise

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In Microsoft SQL 2008 Enterprise manager, when you right click a table to open it the option only grabs the first 1000 rows. Same thing with an edit except it limits the result to 200 rows. Is there a way to increase this in the context menu? I know I change the SQL once it loads, but I'd like to set the default value myself so I don't have to always have to remove the TOP 1000 syntax from the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be found under

> Tools->Options->SQL Server Object
>   Explorer.

Look for

> Value for Edit Top < n > Rows command

and

> Value for Select Top < n > Rows command